# Simulate this effect, jquery draggable

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, draggable, breadcrumbs

Hi I am trying to get a similar effect to so: https://www.tumblr.com/search/html

This is my current code, basically I want the breadcrumbs to scroll left and right, but to stop when the last / first breadcrumb is out of the viewport.

Here is the jsfiddle of my progress so far check the hash tags of each post and they're scrollable if the div is overflowing.

http://jsfiddle.net/omvjuutb/

```
$('#list-container').draggable({
    'axis': 'x',
});
```

Comment: I've updated my js fiddle to emphasize more what I am trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/omvjuutb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may Help You.

```
$(function() {
$( "#list-container" ).draggable({
    'axis':'x',
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        //alert(ui.position.left);
        if(ui.position.left <= 200){
            $(this).draggable( "disable" );
        }
    }

});
$("#list-container").click(function(){
    $(this).draggable("enable");
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks for helping me on the quest of fixing my problem, unfortunately it doesn't do what I require :(

Comment: Thanks you help guided me towards fixing my problem.